# mysql php sorting results including SUMs

Tags: mysql, sum

Im making a browser mafia game, and coding the page where it lists all of the familys / gangs.

Each family has a points rating, made up of the combined SUMs of all its members cash, bullets, exp, etc.

This is my code to loop through to show the family listings:

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as member_count,
 (SELECT SUM(bullets) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_bullets,
 (SELECT SUM(cash) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_cash,
 (SELECT SUM(exp) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_exp,
 (SELECT SUM(killscore) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_ks,
 name, id FROM familys f
```

then during the loop with PHP I work out the total points:

```
$points = $rs[sum_bullets]/500;
$points = $points + $rs[sum_cash]/10000;
$points = $points + $rs[sum_exp]/1000;
$points = $points + $rs[sum_ks];
```

Now onto the question. I want to order the results using `ORDER BY points DESC`. How can I adjust my query to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to shift logic from application to MySQL to make it faster with a single query as:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as member_count,
    (SELECT SUM(bullets) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_bullets,
    (SELECT SUM(cash) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_cash,
    (SELECT SUM(exp) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_exp,
    (SELECT SUM(killscore) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_ks,
    name, id
FROM familys f
ORDER BY (sum_bullets/500 + sum_cash/10000 + sum_exp/1000 + sum_ks);
```

Edit: for output of total_points

```
SELECT a.*, (sum_bullets/500 + sum_cash/10000 + sum_exp/1000 + sum_ks) AS total_points
FROM
    (
     SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as member_count,
        (SELECT SUM(bullets) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_bullets,
        (SELECT SUM(cash) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_cash,
        (SELECT SUM(exp) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_exp,
        (SELECT SUM(killscore) FROM players WHERE status='alive' AND family=f.id) as sum_ks,
        name, id
     FROM familys f
    ) a
ORDER BY (sum_bullets/500 + sum_cash/10000 + sum_exp/1000 + sum_ks) ASC;
```

Comment: thanks, i also need an output from the query of the total points

Answer (score 0):

The points you are calculating with php do not exist yet in your mysql code, so I'd recommend adding the sorting via php. Something like adding all the points into an array and either use default [php array sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) methods or if you are using a multi level arrays, try [Alecander Minkovskys multi sort library](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1594-PHP-Sort-arrays-considering-multiple-values.html)